# Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::setTimestamp()

Tags: php

Getting the above error just on one particular server - but not other servers. Assuming it's a php version issue. 
Here is the code that's triggering the error:

```
//get time interval
    static function get_interval($now, $post_time){
        $datetime1 = new DateTime();
        $datetime1->setTimestamp($now);
```

The last line is causing the problem. Any ideas on how to get around it?

Comment: upgrade to 5.3.0+ ? If you can't for some reason, implement the method yourself (check out the 2nd comment from the manual page for that method)

Answer (score 8):

If your PHP version is lower than 5.3 then you can use this class to be able to use the functions "setTimestamp" and "getTimestamp":

```
<?php

class MyDateTime extends DateTime
{
    public function setTimestamp( $timestamp )
    {
        $date = getdate( ( int ) $timestamp );
        $this->setDate( $date['year'] , $date['mon'] , $date['mday'] );
        $this->setTime( $date['hours'] , $date['minutes'] , $date['seconds'] );
    }

    public function getTimestamp()
    {
        return $this->format( 'U' );
    }
}

$date = new MyDateTime();
$date->setTimestamp( $someTimestamp );

echo $date->format( 'd/m/Y H:i:s' );

?>
```